# Mouse sometimes not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mouse

Sometimes when I boot into my Ubuntu system (dual boot) the pointer doesn't move when I move the mouse. The lights on the mouse work so it is enabled. When I reboot Ubuntu it most of the times works again. So it is completely random when it will work or not. I have a Logitech G Pro mouse that connects wireless to a USB dongle.
Any idea what could cause this? On my Windows system I never have this problem.

Comment: Try reconnecting the dongle. If it works without reboot then it's an issue of hardware initialization and if so very hard to almost impossible to troubleshoot as it can be anything ranging from the way the USB hubs/ports are initialized to something specific of the Logitech dongle that somehow is overcome in Windows with proprietary code, expected to exist in the OS for which the product has been developed from the start and not expected to exist anywhere else unless the manufacturer opens up (not happening with Logitech).

Comment: I will try this next time, thanks! When I open terminal when the mouse doesn't work it is visible in xinput tho.

Comment: So I suspect it's something specific to that dongle that isn't initializing correctly in a cold boot (but works as expected otherwise).

Comment: I had the problem again, tried to replug the dongle but didn't help. Did some google searches and found Solaar, going to try that now.

Comment: No idea if it's because of Solaar or just a coincidence, but I didn't have the problem for a few times now.